# Any affine conic is isomorphic to $V(y-x^2)$ or $V(xy-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, conic-sections

[image]

I'm trying to solve the above exercise in Ghatmann's notes on algebraic geometry.

I tried to consider the real case and I suspect that X1 should correspond to a plane that intersects with exactly one of the cones, whereas X2 is the case in which both cones are intersected (not at the origin).

Next i tried to look at the general case of a quadratic polynomial in two variables to see what happens if I act on it with an affine change of coordinates(i.e. linear transformation followed by translation), this quickly got very complicated.

My guess is that I need to figure out how the irreducibility condition affects the general equation, and maybe extend the intuition I gained for the real case to arbitrary fields(of characteristic $\ne$ 2).

However, right now I'm kind of stuck, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Note that the field $K$ is assumed to be algebraically closed.

Comment: I assume $K$ is algebraically closed?

Comment: Yeah, it's closed. I will edit my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $K$ is algebraically closed, with characteristic not $2$.

Suppose your irreducible conic is given by $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$ (up to a constant factor).

Consider the quadratic form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$. Since $K$ is algebraically closed, this factors into a product of homogeneous linear forms, $a\ell_1\ell_2$, with $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ monic in $x$. If $\ell_1=\ell_2$, then let $dx+ey=d\ell_3$. If $\ell_3=\ell_1$ as well, then we could rewrite our equation as $a\ell_3^2 + d\ell_3 + f=0$, which is reducible, since $K$ is algebraically closed. Otherwise, $\ell_3 \ne \ell_1$, so let $x'=\sqrt{-a}\ell_1$, $y'=d\ell_3 + f$ to get that our original conic is given by $y' - x'^2$ in our new variables.

Otherwise, if $\ell_1\ne \ell_2$, take $x_1=a\ell_1$, $y_1=\ell_2$, and rewrite our conic in terms of $x_1$ and $y_1$, so that it is of the form
$$x_1y_1+Ax_1 + By_1+C =0.$$
Let $x_2=x_1+B$, $y_2=y_1+A$, so that the conic can be rewritten as 
$$x_2y_2 + (C-AB)=0.$$
If $C-AB=0$, then the conic is reducible, so finally
let $x'=x_2$, $y'=\frac{-1}{C-AB}y_2$, so that
$$x'y' -1=0,$$
as desired.